Barcode detected on second button press
I just want to find out what is causing barcode detection from image only working on second attempt (button press) even on examples like this:
https://zxing-js.github.io/library/examples/barcode-image/
If i press DECODE once it shows N in Result and only show barcode detected on second press.
Is this something with my setup as i used different browsers on Linux Ubuntu or something that needed to be fixed?
Thank You
I tried changing my code in many ways until i saw that code on examples have same issue.

Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.
